# Writing a Byte Array to a Range in Excel VBA without looping

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to dump an array to a worksheet directly without looping. This is possible for all data types, except a 'Byte' array. Why is this so?

I want to use Byte array, so as to save memory cost (data often exceeds the 2GB excel limit). While I have worked around this problem by dividing into chunks, I want to understand why a Byte array can't be dumped into a range directly.

**edit 1:**

The array value is either 0 or 1. And I want the output shown as it is.
Using a Boolean array gives it as TRUE or FALSE, which I don't prefer.
Any optimized(memory and speed) ways to do this?

```
Sub ArrayPasting()

    Dim byteArray(1 To 3) As Byte
    Dim intArray(1 To 3) As Integer

    For i = 1 To 3
        byteArray(i) = i
        intArray(i) = 2 * i
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Value = intArray    'range populated with intArray
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 3)).Value = byteArray   'error

End Sub
```

Comment: Bytes arrays are typically for binary data which cannot be represented as printable text so cannot be treated like other types where there is always a readable representation.  "*so as to save memory cost*" probably needs some clarification.

Comment: @AlexK."so as to save memory cost" - Using a byte array would consume lesser memory space than an integer. this way I could reduce the number of chunks that has to be processed and dumped, thereby increasing speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have a REALLY big Boolean array that we want to:

- dump into cells
- convert to 1/0 *(where TRUE is 1)*

then something like:

```
Sub SayBoo()
    Dim Boo(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Boolean
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1:B2")

    Boo(1, 1) = True
    Boo(1, 2) = True
    Boo(2, 1) = False
    Boo(2, 2) = False
    r = Boo

    With r
        .Value = Evaluate("=IF(" & .Address & ",1,0)")
    End With

End Sub
```

will do it.

Comment: That's a nice way of doing it. But it takes twice the time (dumping + re-writing).

Comment: @Surya  You are correct.  The potential savings is the memory storage for the BIG array, not speed of execution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Application.transpose (in this case):

```
Sub ArrayPasting()

    Dim byteArray(1 To 3) As Byte
    Dim intArray(1 To 3) As Integer

    For i = 1 To 3
        byteArray(i) = i
        intArray(i) = 2 * i
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Value = intArray    'range populated with intArray
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 3)).Value = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(byteArray))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store binary array values direclty in Excel. You have to convert them to the format acceptable by Excel. Encode array values as base-64 string. Then you can store it in Excel cell.

Well, if you really need to store binary data in Excel (it's a little bit abusing of Excel. Excel wasn't created for binary data storage) you need to:

1. Convert binary data to text (you are already doing it by base-64 encoding)
2. Split text into smaller chunks and store each piece in separate cell. This way one image would be stored in several cells.

Comment: `Split text into smaller chunks and store each piece in separate cell` - this involves looping, but OP requirement is to NOT use loop.